# Can I add a project to portfolio without copyrights?

Tags: copyright

Being in high school I created my first 3D game. It was basketball game in which all the models where created by me and I put all the logos in them to be as real as possible. The ball has Spalding logo on it, the ads have NBA logo etc. and in the background there is Eminem's music.

Few years later I found an .exe file of the game and would like to add it to my portfolio before sending resume. I am quite happy with this game and it might boost my chances by a lot. But can I put it in my portfolio with all these logos and music?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You paid royalties for all the trademarks and copyrights, yes?

If so, and the portfolio use is in terms with all of the licences you negotiated, yes you can.

If not, no.

These are other people’s IP and they get to decide how it is used. You using it to hone your skills for personal development and consumption is fine. You sharing it with third parties isn’t.